# Azure Function app - Python SDK - How to read Service Bus Message body

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I completed Azure solution: Azure Function, Service Bus, Python SDK code. My Function is triggered by Service Bus message. Function is triggered as expected. Function code below

```
import logging
import json
import requests
import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))


    url = 'WebHookURL'
    payload = {"keyA": "valueA"}
    requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Question is how can I get Service bus message nested values.
In Ms documentation I found an example, below, but how to get message `body` details (`'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')`). Message `body` is the core of the solution because in this message `body` there are a lot of `key:value` properties delivered by external service.

```
def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message.')

    result = json.dumps({
        'message_id': msg.message_id,
        'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),
        'content_type': msg.content_type,
        'expiration_time': msg.expiration_time,
        'label': msg.label,
        'partition_key': msg.partition_key,
        'reply_to': msg.reply_to,
        'reply_to_session_id': msg.reply_to_session_id,
        'scheduled_enqueue_time': msg.scheduled_enqueue_time,
        'session_id': msg.session_id,
        'time_to_live': msg.time_to_live,
        'to': msg.to,
        'user_properties': msg.user_properties,
        'metadata' : msg.metadata
    }, default=str)
```

Answer (score 2):

I completed Function App Python code, it looks like below, works as expected, verified and tested.

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):

    result = ({
        'body': json.loads(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')) 
    })

    try:
        resource_name = result.get('body', {}).get('resourceName')

        logging.info('resourceName: %s', resource_name)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)
```

input json content:

```
{
   "resourceName":"testVM",
   "resourceVnet": "Vnet01"
}
```